# Are assets cached in CDN

Tags: caching, cdn

I am currently investigating on reducing my page load time. I use a CDN. I want to know if images, css, js files are cached on a CDN or does the CDN evry time make HTTP requests to the server to fetch these files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes CDN caches a resourse and set `Expires` header for that resourse,after it expires then cdn fetches that resource again.

So if you want CDN to cache a resource for long time then set the `Expires` header to a higher value.

Comment: Only thing to add here is that most modern CDN will provide a GUI with an option to control caching rules - usually in bulk (e.g., cache all JS, cache all .jpg file in /images/, etc). 
Some will also provide an "auto-pilot" option that will use usage data to intelligently identify caching opportunities and optimized refreshing rates. This will help cache dynamically generated objects  and dynamically rendered HTML.